# Connect Health agent - Firewall rules (Outbound connectivity to the Azure service endpoints)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm looking for some guidance on this article:
Azure AD Connect Health agent installation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-health-agent-install

Down here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-health-agent-install#outbound-connectivity-to-the-azure-service-endpoints
we aren't certain which ports must be opened for the first 4 "General public" endpoints:
.blob.core.windows.net
.aadconnecthealth.azure.com
.servicebus.windows.net - Port: 5671 (This endpoint isn't required in the latest version of the agent.)
.adhybridhealth.azure.com/

I'm not really concerned about #3, assuming I shouldn't have problems with the latest agent. But for 1,2, and 4, I don't know if opening port 443 on firewall would be sufficient.

Comment: Hello @Dennis K, as per the requirements in the document it says that only 443 port is required for the latest agent.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   Opening the port 443 in your on-premises environment for outbound connectivity to the specified URLs is not enough, you also need to check for TLS filter inspection on your firewall also whether certificate inspection and verification is enabled or not and if enabled then bypass the stated endpoint URLs in the HTTPS inspection exclusion list.

•   Also, bypass the list of endpoint URLs in Internet Explorer enhanced security list of allowed websites on the Azure AD Connect server while also ensuring that FIPS (Federal Information Processing Standard) is disabled on that Server where Azure AD Connect Health Agent is installed. You can disable the FIPS through group policy if it is enabled on your environment by not applying that GPO on that server.

•   Once the Azure AD Connect Health Agent is installed on the server and all the prerequisite ports and required endpoint URLs are bypassed in outbound configuration from firewalls and gateway filtering appliances, test the connectivity to the Azure AD Connect health check service in Azure by testing the same by executing the following command on that server and checking its results.

```
  ‘ Test-AzureADConnectHealthConnectivity ’
```

For more information, please refer the below links: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee796230(v=technet.10)